Geometry Nodes Looping Animaton Question
I have this geometry nodes animation that loops through an index, and translates them over one by one. I want to make it so that the cones continue to move, inching further and further, but I'm confused on how to make the loop.
I want to iterate through every instance in the index, translate them, and then iterate through every one of them again.
If you have any resources for understanding this, or solutions that would be great! Thanks

Put the translations inside a "simulation zone" node. The input is the "create cones" thing, the output is the translated instances.
